# Central Limit Theorem and Confidence Intervals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I will appreciate the assistance with the following task:

The meteorological station, which is located in the botanical garden of Sydney, registers the amount of precipitation from 1885. The average annual rainfall for the period from 1885 to 2015 inclusive is 1197.69 mm, the sample variance is 116182.2.

Considering that the annual rainfall is a random variable that does not vary in time and has a normal distribution, construct an interval that will contain the probability of 99.7% of the precipitation amount that will fall in 2016.

1.What is its upper limit? Round the answer to two characters after the decimal point.

2. Estimate the value of the parameter σ¯n - the standard deviation of the normal distribution, which, according to the central limit theorem, approximates the distribution of the average amount of precipitation per year from the previous problem. Round the answer to two characters after the decimal point.
3. Build an approximate 99.7% confidence interval for the average rainfall for the year. What is the upper limit of confidence? Round the answer to two characters after the decimal point.

Comment: Please have a look at the [formula that I have](https://image.prntscr.com/image/75d813b9534848bb9d3637cf4113d399.png) I have no idea of how to find Z.

Comment: It seems, that I am trying to calculate the confidence interval for the general average (mathematical mean value). And I need to find an interval containing a random variable.

Comment: I need to find an interval (not a confidant one) in which the probable amount of precipitation falls in 2016.

Comment: Please comment your downvotes! Thank you.

Comment: Downvotes (none of them mine) are _probably_ because you have not shown us what you have tried or provided additional context. // I think the terminology you want is 'confidence interval' and 'prediction interval'. // My 'Answer' below may help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Central Limit Theorem, $\bar X = 1197.69$ is an observation from an approximately normal distribution. Assuming that you have independent observations over a period of $n$ years,
a 95% *confidence* interval for the true mean annual rainfall $\mu$ would be of
the style $\bar X \pm 2 S\sqrt{1/n},$ where $S$ is the sample standard deviation and $n$ is over a hundred.

A corresponding 95% *prediction* interval for rainfall in an additional year
(not used in determining $\bar X$ or $S$) would be 
$\bar X \pm 2S\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}}.$

I realize this is not a direct answer to your question, but it ought to be
close enough to allow you to get to the relevant section in your text and
make necessary adjustments for the exact question you are expected to answer.

Comment: I can't vote up yet. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that helped, up-vote or not. // But when you get _the_ answer you want to a question, you can click to 'Accept', so it goes off our list of questions yet to be answered. // Suggest you 'take the tour' of the site. That will help you ask better-focused questions, let you know site rules, and gain you a few 'reputation' points.

Comment: I will mark your post as an answer. However, I found the correct formulas and answered by myself. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Glad you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for all questions is as follows:

[image]